# Open a video editor for a video file

Tags: android, kotlin, android-intent

I am writing an app that is browsing images and videos. When I click on the video I can open a video player successfully, but I would like to add a feature for opening the clicked file in a video editor. The following code does not find any activities and does not call the startActivity() function. I have apps on the same phone that can open editors for videos.

```
Intent().apply {
    if(!File("$mediaPath/${mediaItem.name}").exists()){
        log.e("Not existing: $mediaPath/${mediaItem.name}")
        return
    }
    val action = Intent.ACTION_EDIT
    setDataAndType(Uri.parse("$mediaPath/${mediaItem.name}"), "video/*")    
    val activities = packageManager.queryIntentActivities(this, 0);
    val isIntentSafe = activities.size > 0;
    if (isIntentSafe) {
        startActivity(this);
    } else {
        Snackbar.make(view, "There are no intents for editing a video",
            Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).setAction("Action", null).show()
        log.e("no intents available");
    }
}
```

If I change the MIME type to "image/*" my app can open image editors.

Answer (score 0):

I could solve my problem by replacing this line

```
setDataAndType(Uri.parse("$mediaPath/${mediaItem.name}"), "video/*")
```

with this one

```
setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(File("$mediaPath/${mediaItem.name}")), "video/*")
```

Comment: I can't find any app that answer to that intent for a video, any example?